# MySQL comparison issue with high utf-8 codepoints

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I'm seeing weird behavior with MySQL and very high UTF-8 code points.

A couple examples ( -> \u{1f48f} or \u{1f48e} or anything else up that ballpark)

```
SELECT name, '', name = '', '' = '', name = '' from payees where id = 4178417368;
+------+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| name |    | name = '' | '' = '' | name = '' |
+------+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|      |  | 1           | 0         | 1         |
+------+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
1 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Notice that equality has become non-transitive: name is equal to the empty string, name is equal to random character, but random character is not equal to empty string.

Granted this is on a fairly old version of MySQL 5.1.68. Does anybody know it this is still the case in newer versions of MySQL 5.1 or 5.x in general?

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL **`utf8`** characterset only supports characters in the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). It does not support any characters in the Supplementary planes.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html

MySQL 5.5.x  introduced a **`utf8mb4`** characterset which does support 4-byte encoding; the behavior of the **`utf8`** characterset remains the same.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

---

From what you've posted, it looks like the value stored in the `name` column of that row is a zero length string. (You could use the LENGTH(name), CHAR_LENGTH(name), HEX(name) functions to get a better idea of what's actually stored there.

The equality comparison of the `name` column to an empty string, and to an unsupported character do look like they should be returning 1.

But the result of the comparison of two literals returning 0, I didn't really expect that. There's no column characterset involved there, so that's going to be just the client characterset. I'd be tempted to use the LENGTH, CHAR_LENGTH and HEX functions on that literal.

The result of the comparison of those literals is either 1) documented behavior (documented somewhere), or 2) undefined behavior, and MySQL can do whatever it does, or 3) it's a bug (i.e. the behavior deviates from the documented behavior.)